# Creating a neural network with my own dataset - ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Right now my code is throwing that error and I'm not sure why I have tried converting the arrays into 3d arrays the error is being thrown in the model.fit section I believe my error may be with creating my dataset I dont believe its a type error i think it be most likely that there is something wrong with the dimension of my array but im really not sure  if anyone could help that would be great heres my code -

```
    from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from numpy import asarray
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



black_people = os.path.join(os.curdir, 'black people')




numpydata_black = []
for root, _, files in os.walk(black_people):
    # make sure to only get the imgs (ignore .DS_Store)
    for file in filter(lambda f: str(f).endswith(".png"), files):
        img = Image.open(os.path.join(root, file))
        numpydata_black.append(np.array(img))
numpydata_black = asarray(numpydata_black, dtype=object)



white_people = os.path.join(os.curdir, 'black people')


numpydata_white = []
for root, _, files in os.walk(white_people):
    # make sure to only get the imgs (ignore .DS_Store)
    for file in filter(lambda f: str(f).endswith(".png"), files):

        img = Image.open(os.path.join(root, file))
        numpydata_white.append(np.array(img))
numpydata_white = asarray(numpydata_white, dtype=object)


twod_array = []

for image in numpydata_white:
    white_images = [image/255.0, 'white']
    twod_array.append(white_images)


for image in numpydata_black:
    black_image = [image/255.0, 'black']
    twod_array.append(black_image)


class_label = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

class_names = ['White','Black']

twod_array = np.array([np.array(val) for val in twod_array])


model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32, 32)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

twod_array = np.asarray(twod_array)
class_label = np.asarray(class_label)

print(type(twod_array))
model.fit(twod_array, class_label, epochs=5)
```

Comment: Add stacktrace please

Comment: Hi @snoopyballz901, please include the complete traceback in the question. There are no errors in the code; the issue may be with the dataset. Please refer to this [gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/915da45901bb037b1d555044eb5efb7b/73038849.ipynb#scrollTo=T4WQWAvIxDYP) where I reshaped the data to avoid the error. Thank you!